# What is the word for describing something old?

Tags: word-request

What is the word for something that is dysfunctional because of it being old and in use for a very long time?

I was having a conversation with my friend yesterday about the earphones I use with my computer:

> Friend: Your earphones are horrible, one side does not work and voice is also disturbed.
>
> Me: What do you expect? I have been using them for the past two years, this is how long they last.

When I was imagining this conversation about keys, I described keys as rusty, which will imply that they are old. Is there a word along the same line for dysfunctional cars, computers, or something similar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, you can say things are **worn out**.

> What do you expect?  I've been using them for the past two years.  They're **worn out**!

For many objects, there are alternative words, but they're less general:

For your car example, I'd say **dilapidated**.  This word works best for larger, more complex objects.  A house or car can be dilapidated, but the phrases <sup>?</sup>*dilapidated keys* and <sup>?</sup>*dilapidated headphones* sound weird to me.  You can also say a car is **broken down**, but only if it doesn't actually move.

For keys, I agree that **rusty** works, but only if they're actually rusty.  If they're worn down, I'd say they're **worn**.

Sometimes you don't need a special word.  I might complain about my **broken old** headphones.  You could also say they're **in a state of disrepair**, but it doesn't sound very conversational to me.

---

<sup>?</sup> This symbol means "*This phrase is of dubious acceptability.  I suggest you avoid this phrase.*"

Comment: Will not work for things like "genitalia".

Answer (score 4):

In addition to previously-suggested *[worn out](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/worn_out#Adjective)* (“Damaged and useless due to hard or continued use”) and *[dilapidated](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dilapidated#Adjective)* (“Having fallen into a state of disrepair or deterioration, especially through neglect”), and the less-appropriate *[antiquated](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antiquated#Adjective)* (“old-fashioned, out of date”),  consider the phrases  *[run down](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run-down)* (“being in poor repair : dilapidated”) and *[beat-up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beat-up#Adjective)* (“(chiefly of an object) Worn out by overuse; in a state of disrepair”).

Note, *run-down* is more often used to describe poor-condition houses, buildings, and neighborhoods than to describe small items like headphones.

Answer (score 3):

You might get some mileage out of describing them as **legacy hardware**. Computer geeks will get it; I'm not sure how much currency it will have outside of that domain.

You could also describe them as **old school**, which is a generally positive expression that means they are from another (older) generation, but were respectably good at the time.

*Old school* is a more modern way of saying **antique**.  If your earbuds are antiques, then they were probably among the first ones made.  If they are antiquated, that means they are extremely out-of-date, but probably still functioning to some degree.

Answer (score 3):

While most commonly used to refer to people, **'decrepit'** also can mean just what you are describing.  Definition 2 from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decrepit) shows:

> 2. a :  impaired by use or wear :  worn-out
>    b :  fallen into ruin or disrepair

That online dictionary actually uses a car in their example of **decrepit** as well:

> My decrepit car barely starts.

Answer (score 2):

For technology, you can describe it as *broken down*, *outdated*, *worn out*, *deprecated* (software only), *dated*, or *dead* / *dying*.

> What do you expect? I have used them for two years; they are dying on me.

Answer (score 0):

outdated. (Headphone speakers have advanced rapidly in the last few years).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen media reports which talk about out-of-date technology, so old it's dysfunctional, describing it using expressions like **dinosaur tech**.

More generally, in the UK there is an expression, **old hat**, used of anything considered *outmoded*, in the sense of being perceived as having antidiluvian or prehistoric origins. And applied not just to machinery but anything, even figures of speech.

A very British phrase is the term **Heath Robinson**, for use in describing an invention that is a bit ramshackle due to its antique origins. This was the name of an inventor (the term scientist is not really appropriate), who was a popular tv personality in the UK in the 1950s, who cobbled together machinery which worked after a fashion. Still used of any equipment that looks to have an element of DIY about it.

Britain also uses, or used until recently, the term **steam driven** for any technology which was so old as to be rumoured to have come out of the Ark (Biblical references still being in use among the older generation).